# How to create a new array in while loop with each iteration?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a while loop that's doing some stuff, and what I want is for it to create a new array each time.

```
while(condition){
//do some stuff
//create an array x[]
//amend values in array
//save as new array each time until loop finished
}
```

Actually i need to store the comma separated values of different datatypes in an array using split.And then i hav to sort these values comparing zeroth position element of all rows.

Comment: do you really want an array, or are you okay with something more dynamic/flexible like a List?

Comment: It sounds like you need to break your problem into parts. From what I understood, you need to a) declare an array –this is trivial and found everywhere, i.e. no good for SO, b) access and modify array items –also trivial and found everywhere, c) you don't really specify how you want to 'save' this array, but that specific question should be a separate question, and I'm willing to bet you'll find answers for *it* if you look.

Answer (score 2):

Declare and create an "array of arrays" before the loop, and add each new array to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a List, as you can just do something simple like this:

```
List<string[]> myArrayList = new List<string[]>();
while(condition)
{
    string[] blah = new string[10];
    blah[0] = "whatever";
    myArrayList.Add(blah);
}
```

---

**Edit:** to read stuff back out of the `List<>` of arrays, just do a `foreach`:

```
foreach (string[] myArray in myArrayList)
{
    //each instance of 'myArray' is one of the arrays you added previously

    for (int ii = 0; ii < myArray.Length; ii++)
    {
        string myString = myArray[ii];

        //do stuff with my array entry
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sap, check my edit. You just need to iterate over the list you created, each item in the list is one of the individual arrays you added.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need some specific help.  If you don't know how many arrays you'll create I suggest a List<[element type]>...

```
List<List<int>> outerList = new List<List<int>>();
while(condition)
{
   List<int> loopList = new List<int>();

   loopList.Add(5);
   loopList.Add(1);
   loopList.Add(27);

   outerList.Add(loopList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] x = new double[5] { 20, 15, 25, 10, 5 };
Array.Sort(x);

double vaule = 0;
double y = 0;

while (y < 5)
{
    if (vaule < x[(int)y++]);
    {
        vaule = x[(int)y++];
    }
    y++;
}

double[] myarray = Convert.ToString(x[5]);
```